# How to properly encode single quote and & in url

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am New to classic asp. In one of the pages i am getting two variable which I have to send to some other page. Now one of the variable may contain "'" or "&" symbol. Since both of them had different meaning i tried encoding them using following code:

```
    encodeData = replace(encodeData,"&", "%26")
    encodeData = replace(encodeData,"'", "%27")
```

Now suppose my variable has **Miscellaneous & Reports** it is encoded as **Miscellaneous %26 Reports**. This is fine, But suppose it has Nikhil's it is getting encoded as **Nikhil%26#39;s**. Due to this on next page i am getting **Nikhil&**. What is the correct way to encode it. I am using Only classic asp, no java-script etc.

Comment: [Server.URLEncode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx) ?

Comment: I tried applying it to whole url and failed, later i applied this function only to encode the variable and it solved my purpose. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the standard ASP function

`Server.URLEncode(string)`

In your case:

`Server.URLEncode("Nikhil's")`

will return

`Nikhil%27s`

This should solve your issue.

Comment: It's been covered by [@SearchAndResQ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1682881/searchandresq) in [the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882083/how-to-properly-encode-single-quote-and-in-url#comment61329893_36882083)